# I want to write letters before a numerator like shown below

Tags: fractions

I'm learning Tex and i have this command but i want the following output,
Thanks in advance for the help.

my code;

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    $$  M_{extra} = \frac {Kinetic,Potential,Thermal E}{C^2}$$

    \end{document}
```

I want this [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use `$$...$$`. It's outdated. Use `\[....\]` instead ... from a typographical point of view this annotation does not look very useful, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer its not about being useful we are learning and it is needed for us in my class. I tried all methods, i thought $$ is for centering?

Comment: @Symbuao: Learning what? LaTeX? Physics? As an educator of Math and Physics, I don't advise to use such a notation. It's confusing

Comment: @ChristianHupfer (you said my name wrongly), Well Physics, Thanks for the advice but confusing in which way? let me ask how do you center it with that? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my result, not exactly your. I hope it can help you.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$m_{extra} = \frac {
 {\tiny  
 \begin{smallmatrix}
        kinetic\\
        potential\\
        thermal
 \end{smallmatrix}
}E}{C^2}$
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

**EDIT (suggestion by Ethan Bolker)**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$m_{\text{\textit{extra}}} = \frac {
 {\tiny  
 \begin{smallmatrix}
        \text{\textit{kinetic}}\\
        \text{\textit{potential}}\\
        \text{\textit{thermal}}
 \end{smallmatrix}
}E}{C^2}$
\end{document}
```

The result is the same, but more correct.

Comment: You should probably use `\text` for the text in the formula. If not, `LaTeX` thinks the `'e', 'x'` etc. are variables.

Comment: Yes, but in the picture the font is italic. Ah! I have understood.

Comment: Just plain `\textit` instead of `\text` rather than in addition works too.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you like something as

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{fouriernc}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{equation*}% <---------------------------------
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    M_{\text{extra}} =
\frac{\text{\itshape\bfseries\begin{tabular}[b]{l}
        Kinetic     \\
        Potential   \\
        Thermal
      \end{tabular}}{\!\!\text{%
\fontsize{46}{11}\itshape E}
     }} % end of the numerator
    {C^2}
\end{equation*}
    \end{document}
```

... just my 2 cents ...

Answer (score 1):

And another variant, which uses a tabular for the kind of energies and resizes the symbol *E* to the height of the tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\[
  M_{\text{extra}} = \frac{
    \sbox0{\footnotesize
      \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
        kinetic\\potential\\thermal
      \end{tabular}%
    }\copy0
    \resizebox{!}{\ht0}{\Huge$E$}
  }{C^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The `tabular` environments also add struts, which makes the size of *E* a little larger than the top of the letters of "kinetic". Therefore a version with package `varwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\[
  M_{\text{extra}} = \frac{
    \sbox0{\footnotesize
      \begin{varwidth}[b]{\linewidth}
        kinetic\\potential\\thermal
      \end{varwidth}%
    }\copy0
    \resizebox{!}{\ht0}{\Huge$E$}
  }{C^2}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with varwidth]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 M_{\text{extra}} = 
\frac {
\begin{array}{l}
\text{Kinetic} \\
\text{Potential} \\
\text{Thermal}
\end{array}
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{E}}}}
} % end of the numerator
{C^2}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```